# Ephemeral network interfaces

Tags: ubuntu, networking, network-interface

I'm on Ubuntu 20.04 and each other time when I access a web page, Chrome says "Your connection was interrupted ERR_NETWORK_CHANGED".

Running `watch -n.1 ifconfig` shows my cable, wireless and loopback interfaces and an additional interface named `vethRandomSuffix`. This interface always disappears from ifconfig output when its `TX packets` reaches 20, then another `vethRandomSuffix` appears.

Example veth interface:

```
veth9f101b1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::e0b1:cff:fe00:aa24  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether e2:b1:0c:00:aa:24  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 3  bytes 126 (126.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 14  bytes 1954 (1.9 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Before I observed this problem, I had many veth interfaces created by VirtualBox, so I uninstalled VirtualBox and then removed all the veth interfaces using this answer: https://superuser.com/a/1307218.

I would appreciate if someone could tell me a way to find what process keeps bringing these interfaces up and down.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, Docker also creates interfaces named `vethRandomSuffix`.
I must had brought down one of Docker interfaces when I cleaned them.

My solution was restarting docker service
`sudo service docker restart`.